# Segmentation fault error while converting string to integer using atoi function

Tags: c, atoi

While am trying to convert a string to an integer using atoi function, I do not get any output.
Upon debugging, it shows segmentation fault error in the line `t=atoi(s[i]);`
Here's the code for your reference:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char s[100];
  int i=0,t;
  printf("Enter: ");
  fgets(s,100,stdin);
  while(s[i]!='\0')
  {
    if(s[i]>='1' && s[i]<='9')
    {
      t = atoi(s[i]);
      printf("%d\n",t);
    }
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing a *character* to `atoi` instead of a string address. Try `t = atoi(s + i);` There should have been a compiler warning - don't ignore them.

Comment: `s[i]` is a char. but `atoi` expects a string. You could use `atoi(&s[i])` to read the number starting at `i`.

Comment: Note: after reading a number with `atoi`, you should _skip_ all digits following `s[i]` because you have just processed them. A  bit more to do than just `i++`.

Comment: Replace the entire `while()` loop with `int x = atoi(s); printf("%d\n", x);`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Weather Vane @ Paul Ogilvie @ chux - Reinstate Monica. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings:

Running the posted code through the `gcc` compiler results in:

```
gcc   -O1  -ggdb -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11  -c "untitled2.c"  -I. (in directory: /home/richard/Documents/forum)

untitled2.c: In function ‘main’:

untitled2.c:14:16: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘atoi’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
       t = atoi(s[i]);
                ^

In file included from /usr/include/features.h:424:0,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/libc-header-start.h:33,
                 from /usr/include/stdio.h:27,
                 from untitled2.c:1:

/usr/include/stdlib.h:361:1: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
 __NTH (atoi (const char *__nptr))
 ^

untitled2.c:9:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fgets(s,100,stdin);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

in other words, this statement:

```
t = atoi(s[i]);
```

is passing a single character to the function: `atoi()`  But, `atoi()` expects to be passed a pointer to a char array.

From the MAN page for `atoi()`, the syntax is:

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

suggest: replacing:

```
t = atoi(s[i]);
printf("%d\n",t);
```

with:

```
printf( "%d\n", s[i] );
```

Which will output the ASCII value of each of the characters in the array `s[]`.   As an example the ASCII value of '1' is 49.

Note that modern compilers output warns about failing to check the returned value from C library functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user3629249.

Comment: @user36 use `%c` instead of `%d` in  `printf( "%d\n", s[i] );` is nicer ?